# manage code versioning with Bitbucket from existing project in VS2012

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2012, bitbucket

I've developed a VS2012 project in C# and I would like to use Bitbucket for versioning.

I have two versions of the software (1.0 and 1.1). Further modifications and new functionalities will be made to create the 1.2 version.

I would like to store, in a BitBucket repository, both the freezed versions 1.0 and 1.1 and, when it will be ready, to commit the new 1.2 version.
Can I create the 1.0 and 1.1 in the same repository or it is better to have a repo for 1.0 and one for 1.1?

Obviously, I suppose that the 1.2 will be in the same repo of the 1.1

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I got what you mean by versioning. Are you talking about source control versioning? In that case, I'd propose to use branching or tags.

If you plan on supporting and making changes to 1.0 and 1.1, make a branch. Otherwise, just tag the commit with appropriate version.

If you already have 1.0 and 1.1, you can commit 1.0, then copy over the files of 1.1, commit the changes as 1.1 and start developing 1.2 from what you have. Does it make sense?

Comment: Modifications and bug resolutions will be available only in future versions, so I only need to "freeze" the previously developed versions. Maybe the last part of your answer is what I need to do, that is commit 1.0 then add /modify files to reach the 1.1 and start developing for 1.2. Thanks a lot!